# How can I get list of instances where stackdriver monitoring agent is not installed in gcp?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud, libcloud

I have 100's of instances I want to make sure that stackdriver monitoring agent is installed in all my gcp instances. Is there any way I can get a list of instances which does not have stackdriver monitoring agent installed in a project or the other way around either by using python modules or gcloud?

Comment: What is the use case? As in how will you use this data if you know where its installed. Ideally i expect agent to be installed from either Ansible/Terraform. So its configuration should give you the details?

Comment: There are lot of frequent instances being created so it becomes hard to keep a track and we cannot use ansible/terraform as rhel repo does not connect to internet so its not direct to install monitoring agent.

Comment: I dont think it is supported at the moment. But you can write a wrapper using the Monitoring agent API count https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_agent#agent-agent

Comment: @Prashant is there any way I get memory usage data of instances using gcloud? since memory usage does not come for instances which does not have monitoring agent I can figure that part then?

Comment: You mean this one  https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_agent#agent-memory ?

Comment: I would write a program that lists my instances. Then I would list the instances in Stackdriver via the log name. Compare the list. I am not aware of a tool that does this for you. Note that the monitoring agent and the logging agent are different software.

Answer (score 0):

You could query the agent version when you connect through SSH from the Cloud Shell

```
gcloud compute ssh INSTANCE-NAME -- "dpkg-query --show --showformat \
    '${Package} ${Version} ${Architecture} ${Status}\n' \
     stackdriver-agent" --zone=INSTANCE-ZONE
```

Option [--](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh#SSH_ARGS) of [gcloud compute ssh](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh) allows you to send arguments to the SSH command , from there you can just [list the agent version](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/install-agent#agent-version) and if it is not installed it will not return a version